# Clockwork Mod tether stopped working recently

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, tethering

I am using moto g4 and windows 10. The symptom is: when starting the windows app and clicking start button, the application starts normally: the log windows fills up and the button changes to "stop". After a few seconds, thou, the wording on the button changes back to "start", the log stops updating, and there is not connection

Anyone else experienced this? any quick fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have being a problem with my USB cable. I tried again with a new one and now it works just fine. highly recommended app